# Termo equivalente a "cramming" no contexto educacional

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução-inglês

Qual termo ou expressão poderia traduzir o significado de ***cramming***, ainda que exija uma nota de rodapé? A expressão original em inglês vem bem explicada na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramming_(education)) (minha tradução livre):

> Em educação, “cramming” […] é trabalhar intensamente para absorver grande quantidade de informação num curto espaço de tempo. Fazem-no frequentemente os estudantes para se prepararem para exames, especialmente nas vésperas. Normalmente a prioridade do estudante é uma memorização irrefletida apropriada para uma examinação superficial, e não uma verdadeira compreensão da matéria [...]

---

### Contexto e pesquisa prévia:

O jogo [How to Remember Anything Forever-ish](https://ncase.me/remember/) está sendo traduzido para português, e sou  o voluntário encarregado principal. Sou do Brasil, porém dentro do possível estou procurando algo que poderia ser (ainda que com nota de rodapé) intuitivo para falantes de outras regiões, como em Angola que até tenho colegas.

O termo *cramming* não é tão importante no respectivo jogo como outros termos chaves como *Spaced Repetition* e *Forgetting Curve*, porém ele tem peso ao ser reusado não apenas como frase, mas como palavra a ser aprendida. Por isso que talvez, em vez de usar o termo em inglês, até valeria a pena usar algum termo perfeitamente equivalente que até exista em algum outro país que já fale português, e tal sentido seja explicado como nota de rodapé e adicionalmente informado o original em inglês.

Comment: Emerson, vê o que eu fiz à tua pergunta. Se não gostares, clica em "edit", canto inferior esquerdo, e clica em "rollback" (volta à tua versão original) ou altera como desejares. A pergunta é tua. Mas eu achei que o mais importante é dar logo na pergunta a definição de "cramming" . Também me parece que fica mais bonito e legível se os links aparecerem como um nome em vez do endereço web.

Comment: @Jacinto seu edit ficou ótimo! Realmente, melhorou!

Answer (score 5):

Ah! palavras da minha juventude. Em Portugal, o melhor equivalente a *cramming* é ***empinanço***, que é o ato de ***empinar***. Muito próximo tens ***marranço***, ato de ***marrar***. Encontrei os verbos usados no sentido pretendido em sites angolanos.

Estes termos são informais, mas vêm nos dicionários baseados em Portugal; em dicionários brasileiros só encontrei [*marrar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/marrar) (descrito como lusitanismo) e [*empinanço*](http://www.aulete.com.br/empinan%C3%A7o) no Aulete . Citando o *Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa* (2001; de agora em diante DACL; grafia anterior ao AO90), desenvolvendo as abreviações:

> **empinanço** […] *Familiar* Acção de decorar ou de aprender de cor um assunto, independentemente de o compreender ou não; acto ou efeito de empinar. *Foi cá um empinanço de datas e nomes antes do teste! Só mesmo por empinanço conseguiu memorizar tantos conteúdos.*

Isto vem de *empinar* (DACL):

> **empinar** […] **6.** *Familiar* Aprender de cor; pôr na memória […] *Empinar a matéria; não basta empinar, é preciso perceber*.

Eu associo estes significados, e imagino que seja essa a sua origem, a *empinar* no sentido de ‘emborcar’, pôr o copo ou garrafa a pino e beber tudo de uma vez.

***Marrar*** é muito próximo (DACL)

> **marrar** […] **5.** *Gíria* Estudar e, sobretudo, decorar. *Passou três dias a marrar para os exames*.

O DACL não traz ***marranço***, mas a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/marran%C3%A7o) (dicionário da Porto Editora) traz:

> 1. *gíria académica* ato ou efeito de marrar ou decorar
> 2. *gíria académica* estudo afincado, geralmente na véspera de um exame

Na minha experiência, enquanto *empinar* é mesmo só decorar para o exame, mesmo que não se compreenda bem e se esqueça tudo dois dias depois, *marrar* não tem necessariamente essa implicação. E na minha juventude, um verdadeiro [***marrão*** (Infopédia 3.3)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/marr%C3%A3o) era aquele que passava a vida a estudar; não era só na véspera do exame e não necessariamente para esquecer depois do teste. Mas “passou a véspera do exame no marranço” dá no mesmo que “no empinanço”. A infopédia também traz com mais ou menos o mesmo significado [*martelar* (4)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/martelar) e [*martelanço*.](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/martelan%C3%A7o)

Encontrei *empinar* e *marrar* em sites angolanos, usados exatamente com o sentido que eu conheço (negrito meu):

> Muitas crianças sentam-se às secretárias a ouvir os professores, que debitam informação. Isto para o cérebro é muito aborrecido. O cérebro desliga, não tem qualquer interesse. No sistema educativo, obrigam-nos a **empinar** coisas de uma forma que o cérebro não gosta, não é adequado, nem eficaz.
>   [*Portal de Angola*, 2015.](https://www.portaldeangola.com/amp/2015/03/06/treinar-a-memoria-para-aprender-mais-rapidamente-video/)
>
> Quando o professor lia no dia anterior o que ia ser a aula, eu decorava automaticamente. O meu irmão e os outros tinham de **marrar** e eu tinha aquilo matematizado e nem me apercebia.
>   [*AngoNotícias*, 2016](http://www.angonoticias.com/Artigos/item/52963/a-minha-alma-e-atlantica-porque-sou-angolano-vivi-no-brasil-e-em-portugal)

Comment: Bom post, exaustivo. Não faltam vocábulos para o dito comportamento na nossa língua. Somos uns estudiosos...

Comment: @bad_coder, é, entretanto ouvi a um amigo aqui de Setúbal, com o mesmo significado, *encornar*.

Answer (score 2):

No Brasil, nunca ouvi nenhum dos termos mencionados na ótima [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5611/2764) do Jacinto; penso que em pt-br só temos mesmo expressões, não um termo para esse conceito. Me parece que a expressão mais comum, mencionada também no [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/pt/dictionary/english-portuguese/cram), é "**estudar de última hora**".

Um conceito relacionado (talvez relevante, mas não sinônimo) é a `decoreba` (que vem do verbo decorar).

Comment: Tens que começar a usar "empinanço" e "marranço". Não é vergonha nenhuma; somos só dez milhões, mas lá conseguimos ir inventando umas expressões castiças de vez em quando :)

Comment: Tenho um dicionário brasileiro de inglês-português (Webster-Houaiss, Rio de Janeiro, 1982) que indica "virada final" e "dar uma virada final" para "cramming" e "to cram". Conheces neste sentido? Numa vista de olhos pela net, encontrei "virada final" usado apenas noutros contextos ('esforço para virar a situação na ponta final').

Comment: Não, não lembro de já ter visto ela sendo usada nesse sentido.

Answer (score 1):

No Brasil, na minha época de vestibular era muito comum ouvir os colegas dizerem que iam "fazer um intensivão" ou "intensivar", para se referir a essa prática de "cramming".

Apesar de "intensivão" ser uma palavra que não consta no dicionário PT-BR, ela é comum entre os estudantes, é apropriada para o contexto e traduz com relativa fidelidade a ideia de "cramming".

Se o seu texto permitir o uso de neologismos, eu usaria essa expressão sem hesitar.

Comment: Creio que há diferença entre intensivão e _cramming_. Nunca participei de cursos pré-vestibular mas me recordo dos "intensivões" como sendo uma maratona de aulas dadas sobre determinada matéria pelos professores de cursos preparatórios para vestibular, em que, além de apresentar/relembrar conceitos, eram dados e corrigidos exercícios em aula. Não deixa de ser uma espécie de _"cramming"_, porque é um estudo ou decoreba intensivos em um curto período de tempo, mas tem mais a ver com aulas acompanhadas de exercícios e não com estudo individual ou coletivo apenas entre estudantes.

Comment: Há também o termo "aulão", que me parece ter um contexto semelhante.